# Solidity library @openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol is not resolving ownerOnly()

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin

I am trying to switch my contract to use the 'import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol”’, but I am getting the following error

contracts/InvoiceTracker.sol:93:9: DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
ownerOnly()

for this code:
function addClient(address _clientID, string memory _name)
public
ownerOnly()
noDupClient(_clientID, _name)
{}

I have installed:
"@openzeppelin/cli": "^2.8.2",
"@openzeppelin/contracts": "^3.1.0",
"@openzeppelin/test-helpers": "^0.5.6”

Can you give me a clue as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should call onlyOwner() and not ownerOnly()

Answer (score 1):

You must Call the onlyOwner() if you are importing the @openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol. You can't change onlyOwner() to ownerOnly().